# Opamp-based Schmitt trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, non-inverting, inverting

I have attached two opamp-based implementations of Schmitt trigger. Output of one will be inverted when compared with the output of the other circuit. Clearly, the difference is in which terminal the input is given. So in general usage which circuit will be preferred and with what reasons?

[image: Inverting configuration]

**Inverting configuration**

[image: Non-inverting]

**Non-inverting configuration**

Thanks !

Comment: Could you be more specific which "schmitt trigger" implementation you're looking at? -- Please provide a schematic.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The output of inverting Schmitt trigger has 180 degree phase shift
> when compared to non-inverting Schmitt trigger.*

We call this inverting i.e. one is the inverse of the other.

> *Apart from this what are the other differences?*

If you want to talk about phase shift, you should recognize that with a linear (analogue input) the square wave output is phase shifted due to hysteresis i.e. it isn't at all precisely aligned with the input waveform: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-applications-of-a-Schmitt-trigger). So, in-fact, with an analogue input it does produce a kind-of phase shift.

> *In textbook examples I have seen non-inverting configuration being
> used more often than inverting configuration. Is this related with the
> fact that non-inverting op-amp has more bandwidth than inverting op-amp?*

Non-inverting Schmitt trigger **comparators** need to apply positive feedback to the non-inverting input thus, it's more problematic to try and make use of this input for a signal. Hence, we usually see an inverting Schmitt trigger **comparator** followed by a digital inverter.

Comment: yep, it's "kind of" a phase shift – but it assumes perfect "symmetry" of the thresholds in raising and falling direction relative to the average of the analog AC waveform. I really enjoyed this answer!

Comment: @Andy aka Can you please elaborate why positive feedback is more problematic for non-inverting input, and also why inverting Schmitt trigger should be followed by digital inverter ?

Comment: @MAJIDAHMAD what Andy was saying is that if you want to build a non-inverting Schmitt trigger, you built an inverting one, and then invert the output.

Answer (score 7):

> The output of inverting Schmitt trigger has 180 degree phase shift when compared to non-inverting Schmitt trigger.

No, it inverts. That's not a phase shift, unless your signal is a square wave with infinitely steep edges, in which case you don't need any Schmitt triggering to begin with.

Don't go about abusing terms that apply continuous-value, single-fundamental harmonic signals (e.g., sine waves) and systems (e.g., linear low-pass filters) for things that neither have a continuous input/output relationship nor have any aspects to them that make them LTI systems.

> Apart from this what are the other differences ? And in general usage which configuration is preferred more ?

These questions have no clear answer. They are built differently. You obviously prefer the one you need, and have available.

> Is this related with the fact that non-inverting opamp has more bandwidth than inverting opamp ?

no.

1. Schmitt triggers aren't **generally** opamps. If you have to care about bandwidth, you would not build a Schmitt trigger out of elements optimized for linearity, but build it out of elements you can optimize for speed!
2. there's no such thing as an "non-inverting" or "inverting opamp"; "inverting" or "non-inverting" is a property the circuit that you use your opamp in. And which one of these has a higher bandwidth *really* depends on how you implement these. So, I wouldn't even say you can generally say that one has a higher bandwidth than the other.